# What is the point of javascript only polymer components

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

The polymer library has a few components that contain only javascript things.

For example, the google-url-shortener and iron-ajax components do not contain any html or css in them. So then why make them a polymer component instead of just making a javascript library to handle javascript only actions.

Is there some view functionality these components contain that I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can add them declaratively by just adding the tag to the HTML like other elements.
- You can use polymer bindings to connect them with other Polymer elements.